# Add Page Tab Dialog not working via URL

Tags: facebook, dialog, tabs

According to [add to page documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) you should be able to add an app to a page via a URL. The documentation lists two ways of defining the redirect URL `next` and `redirect_uri`

I have tried creating the URL using both methods but get redirected to a Facebook error page from both of them which states:

> Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as
>   soon as we can.

Is there something wrong with how I am creating the URL?

```
string.Format("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/page?app_id={0}&display=popup&redirect_uri={1}", appId, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURL));
```

and

```
string.Format("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/page?app_id={0}&display=popup&next={1}", appId, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURL));
```

UPDATE: It does work via the JavaScript SDK. Any reason why the link I am trying to generate above aren't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you are not using the JS-SDK, you should specify the `redirect_uri`. Most likely the `next` parameter is from an old implementation and no longer in use.
- you are calling the wrong endpoint `/dialog/page`, it should be `/dialog/pagetab`:

Example:

```
string.Format("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id={0}&display=popup&redirect_uri={1}", appId, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURL));
```